# Creating new csv file from existing by removing last 100k rows using Pandas package

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create new csv file from the existing one. My original csv file has 300 000 of records out of which I want 1st 200 000 records. I'm using pandas package from python, as I'm currently working on Machine learning project.
I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv')
df = df.head(2000002)
df.to_csv('solution.csv')
```

as well as

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv')
df = df[:2000002]
df.to_csv('solution.csv')
```

But no success. What should I do to achieve my aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `skipfooter` parameter for omit last `N` rows.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv', skipfooter = 1000000)
```

If want read first N rows use parameter `nrows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv', nrows=2000002)
```